# SVN command to get multiple files size

Tags: svn

How can I get the total size of various files in various location in a SVN server.

I have around 100 file names like "https:\myprojects.svn.com\na\grade1\test\images\img1.png" 
"https:\myprojects.svn.com\na\grade2\main.html"
"https:\myprojects.svn.com\IND\grade3\main.html"...

From the following code I can get the file size individually,

```
svn list -v file_name
```

But, what I want is to get total files size... Is it possible...? Is any SVN command is available?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`svn ls help`

> List **each TARGET file** and the contents of each TARGET directory as
>   they exist in the repository.

You can have multiply unrelated targets as ls parameters

```
>svn ls --verbose http://mayorat.ursinecorner.ru:8088/svn/Hello/branches/i18n/Hello.txt http://mayorat.ursinecorner.ru:8088/svn/Hello/branches/Leichtbau-Deutsch/Hello.en.txt http://mayorat.ursinecorner.ru:8088/svn/Hello/trunk/Hello.en.txt
     23 lazybadg           75 июл 17  2010 Hello.txt
     24 lazybadg           76 июл 17  2010 Hello.en.txt
     33 lazybadg           82 фев 28 16:10 Hello.en.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with following code:

```
svn list --verbose --recursive http://svn/repo/path
```

Comment: The above comment will get the size of particular path. But I have the files in different paths. How can I retrieve the size of all listed files. I mean that shall we pass multiple file names as arguments to svn list command